# Save i18n data with associated table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I want save language localization data of all the associated table. See below example.

There are two tables `Table1` & `Table2`

```
class Table1Table extends App {
   $this->hasOne('Table');
}

class Table1Controller extends Controller
{
   public function index() {
      $data = [
         'Table1' => [
             'field1' => 'aaaa'
         ],
         'Table2' => [
             'field2' => 'bbbb'
         ]
      ];

      $entity = $this->Table1->newEntity($data,[
         'associated' => [
            'Table2'
         ]
      ]);

      $entity->translation('de')->set('field1','aaaa');
      $entity->translation('de')->set('Table2.field1','bbbb');
   }

   $this->Table1->save($entity);
}
```

Here `Table1` i18n data is save but `Table2` i18n data is not save.

Please help me on this concern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have find answer. There are little bit change on the code like below and it's done.

```
$entity->translation('de')->set('field1','aaaa');
$entity->Table2->translation('de')->set('field1','bbbb');
```